# (EDIT)add a sql resource

Tags: xcode4.3

how can I add my database file to my project?

I do as usual, "add files to projectName" and select the sql file, it is supposed added

[image]

but, I have the same response to my code if this is added or not, so, I suppose the resource is not properly added

How should I do it?

Thank you in advance

I did:

[image]

Is that what I should do, isn't it?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if thats the right option..try in visual studio to click once on the sql file and then press f4 (properties), see if you have an option there for "copy always" in copy to output Property

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting up the Copy to output property of the sql file to copy always?

From msdn:

Copy to Output Directory Property
This property specifies the conditions under which the selected source file will be copied to the output directory. Select Do not copy if the file is never to be copied to the output directory. Select Copy always if the file is always to be copied to the output directory. Select Copy if newer if the file is to be copied only when it is newer than an existing file of the same name in the output directory.